# Variations on a Theme

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

### Instructions

The game is to **fill in the blank** with a word or few - no more than three.  No tricksy nonsense.  No hidden meanings.  No "lateral thinking". In fact, only vertical, parallel, dorsal, collinear, and/or perpendicularly derived answers will be accepted.

At the end, name the apparent theme (for the last blank).  Then, name the most bizarre variation you've encountered, along with your personal go-to choice.  Answer now!

> And don't forget not to spoil the fun for others!

### Simple Pleasures, Hidden Treasures

*How popular, you with a piquant manner,

And boldly do you raise the banner.

It might just be some strange bologna?

The consensus garnish is* _____________.

*Alone or in harmony with the aforementioned,

Sliced, earthy gifts for the well-intentioned...

Kids don't enjoy them in their school lunchroom,

But fun guys tolerate the humble* _____________.

*Sometimes the minimum ain't enough.

Above and beyond's how they want the stuff.

"A bit more sprinkled, if you please."

Some like theirs with* _____________.

*What's this you smell (and hold your nose)?

"Somethings fishy," you'll presuppose.

Surely, folks who like them have multiple neuroses.

Who actually relishes canned* _____________?

*It's fresh like IHOP's Rooty Tooty

But feeling merely half as fruity.

Pig out on the rest with an iced tea Snapple®.

My lady's fave must be* _____________.

*Now, I'm of a simpler taste: just the classics.

No need for leftovers resembling some plastics.

Plus, there's less grease in keeping it simple.

Perhaps I'll avoid an extraneous pimple.

The ignorant take it for a well sauced pita.

I stand by the original,* _____________.

*So sorry to bore you with my keen obsession.

It could be the product of sex-'shul repression.

Still, life's greatest treats are but simple pleasure,

Variety adding the spice for good measure.

I don't mean to continue with this name-dropping;

Time to cease listing forms of* _____________.

Comment: +1 already, but just to be clear: is each verse referring to a particular form of [something], and you want people both to fill in the blanks and to find out what this "something" is (filling in the last blank)?

Comment: Yes, each verse's blank is a form of the last verse's blank.  Sorry for the awkward wording.  Basically, last verse's answer is the theme for all the others.

Comment: It wasn't cyanide level, I realize, but hope it was fun.  I'm hungry.  Time for lunch.  Guess what I'm having.

Comment: Definitely a fun riddle! :-) And if it's lunchtime, I deduce you're in America [\sherlock]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The consensus garnish is

> pepperoni

But fun guys tolerate the humble

> mushroom

Some like theirs with

> extra cheese

Who actually relishes canned

> anchovies

My lady's fave must be

> ham and pineapple

I stand by the original,

> margherita

Time to cease listing forms of

> pizza toppings

Most bizarre variation I've encountered:

> seafood (from an Asian Pizza Hut)

My go-to choice:

> sausage

Comment: You're missing half of #3 and #5.  #3 has another word, and #5 has two more.

Comment: @tjbtech Completed #3 and #5.  For #5, "Pig out" is a clue for ham.

Comment: 4 minutes earlier. That's what I get for leaving the window open and not refreshing :P +1

Answer (score 4):

The seventh and final blank, which gives the theme, is surely

> pizza topping!

The first blank (I did see mdc32 and pacoverflow's answers for this one!):

> pepperoni.

Second blank is

> mushroom ("fun guys" is a hint to this, since it sounds like 'fungi').

Third blank could be

> extra cheese?

Fourth blank could be

> anchovies? (doesn't quite rhyme with neuroses, but "fishy" is a hint to this).

Fifth blank is probably

> ham and pineapple (a weird but popular pizza topping; "pig out" is a hint to this).

Sixth blank must be

> margherita (this was the easiest, since it's "just the classics".

The most bizarre variation I've encountered is definitely

> a fried egg.

My go-to choice:

> I love olives on pizza!

Comment: I hate to be picky, but you're only half-right on #3.  Impressed you got #6 so quickly, though!

Comment: @tjbtech - Have I got it now?

Comment: Sure do, but Paco barely beat you to it.  Still +1!

Comment: @tjbtech - Thanks! I've just made my final edit.

Answer (score 2):

As rand'al'thor said, the last one is

> Pizza topping

I think I have them figured out though.

> 1: Pepperoni 
>  2: Mushroom 
>  3: Extra cheese 
>  4: Anchovies? 
>  5: Ham and Pineapple (Hawaiian pizza is great) 
>  6: Margherita

My personal favorite is

> Bacon and garlic sauce. They have it at Domino's (I know, quality pizza), and it's the best I've ever had.

Weirdest variation? None. I'm pretty mainstream, sorry.

Comment: You are also missing part of #5.  Two more words, but so close!

Comment: Everyone gets +1s, huzzah!  But do tell the strangest and your fav, if you still care to.